# Can we create a SharePoint web-hook for any specific folder in a Document Library or for the Document Library itself?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/lists/create-subscription) that we can create subscription web-hook on a list or on entire site.
I want to know if I can create a subscription for a document library or some folder inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation says, the SharePoint list webhooks cover the events corresponding to list item changes for a given SharePoint list or a document library.

So we could create a subscription for a document library, but cannot create it on the folder level.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot, I guess I will try it for document library. I was reading about create subscription and couldn't find there if we could do it also for a document library.